# how to get sort array according to another array in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have one script, in which i have this fields DId(not auto increment) ,Rating ,they are comma separated, the ratings are come from database. now i have to display highest 5 values of ratings and devices according to the ratings.i can find max values of ratings by rsort method then slice the array to 5,but problem is that how can i get the DId according to the ratings. because when rsort an array i lost original indexes of that array, and this script is based on database, and devices will be changed according to the rating each time ratings will be changed. here what i did so far

```
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT DId,Rating FROM wp_ratings1  WHERE QID='1' LIMIT 5,1");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $no1=explode(",",$row['DId']);
    $array_size=count($no1);
    $list = $row['Rating'];
    $array = explode(',', $list);
    rsort($array);
    $res=array_slice($array,0,5);
    print_r($array);


DId        ||   Rating||
36,37,38,     2.3,2.3,4.5, 
39,41,42,     1.0,0,0,
43,44,45,     3.4,1.2,3.12,
46,52,53   ||   2.33,1.22,0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

In your case, I would parse the data and supply it into variable like this:

```
$arrData[0] = array(36=>2.3, 37=>2.3, 38=>4.5);
$arrData[1] = array(39=>1, 41=>0, 42=>0);
$arrData[2] = array(43=>3.4, 44=>1.2, 45=>3.12);
$arrData[3] = array(46=>2.33, 52=>1.22, 53=>0.9);
```

and then process each element and turn it into single array:

```
$arrNew = array();
foreach($arrData as $data){
    foreach($data as $key=>$rating){
        $arrNew[$key]=$rating;
    }
}
```

finally, do [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) on that array.

```
print_r($arrNew);
asort($arrNew);
print_r($arrNew);
```

This is my test result:

```
Array
(
    [36] => 2.3
    [37] => 2.3
    [38] => 4.5
    [39] => 1
    [41] => 0
    [42] => 0
    [43] => 3.4
    [44] => 1.2
    [45] => 3.12
    [46] => 2.33
    [52] => 1.22
    [53] => 0.9
)
Array
(
    [41] => 0
    [42] => 0
    [53] => 0.9
    [39] => 1
    [44] => 1.2
    [52] => 1.22
    [36] => 2.3
    [37] => 2.3
    [46] => 2.33
    [45] => 3.12
    [43] => 3.4
    [38] => 4.5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution would be to use user defined sort :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php